# What on earth happened to my twitter-bootstrap carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

can somebody please help me figure out what I did wrong with this carousel? I pretty much just utilized what was on Bootstrap's intro page. I do believe I have jQuery on my page. Thanks for your help, the following is what it looks like right now:

[image]

Declarations

```
<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css"> 
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

My carousel (I made sure that uploads/hamster.jpg and the others are real and in my folder)

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="uploads/Hamster.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="uploads/sample1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="uploads/Sample2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your script orders are wrong. You should always be loading jQuery first. The main issue is you had the bootstrap js set as a stylesheet and not a script. Also, you are loading jQuery twice which is not necessary and can cause conflicts. Please try the new order below.

```
<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css"> 

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

SECOND ANSWER:

Please see the fiddle below. Copy the code and update the image src/paths. Maybe when you were stripping away the controls you accidentally deleted something else.

**JS Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/x981uzvq/

**Answer:**
 tags are missing type="text/javascript"

Comment: please comment on whether this fixed your problems or not @script kitty, It should help, otherwise there is no point in anyone else attempting to answer this

Comment: Yes, I would also check the image paths. They should still show technically  even if the script orders are messed up.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem and didn't affect what is currently happening.

Comment: @ScriptKitty Double check your image paths as well. The images should still be showing up even if the carousel is broken. I'll put together a JS fiddle for you.

Comment: Thanks so I added my path uploads/Hamster.jpg because I fear I may be missing some obvious thing. I typically miss little details so just in case.

Comment: @ScriptKitty i've updated my answer. Are your views/pages located in the pages folder in regards to the image you posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73715/discussion-between-miura-shi-and-script-kitty).

Comment: Thanks I never could have figured this out on my own. The missing text/javascript ended up not rendering in my browser.